# Measuring performance of object creation in Java

Tags: java, performance, jmh

I'm trying to compare performance of creation the object of some class with creation of `String` from `byte[]`. Here is the benchmark I wrote for this:

```
public class MyBenchmark {
    @Benchmark
    @BenchmarkMode(Mode.AverageTime)
    @OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS)
    public void tsts(Blackhole b) {
        b.consume(new TestClass(i(), str()));
    }

    @Benchmark
    @BenchmarkMode(Mode.AverageTime)
    @OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS)
    public void str(Blackhole b) {
        b.consume(new String(b()));
    }

    @CompilerControl(CompilerControl.Mode.DONT_INLINE)
    public String str(){
        return "asdasfa";
    }

    @CompilerControl(CompilerControl.Mode.DONT_INLINE)
    public int i(){
        return 23;
    }

    @CompilerControl(CompilerControl.Mode.DONT_INLINE)
    public byte[] b(){
        return new byte[]{49, 66, 43, 65, 78, 123, 96, 54};
    }
}
```

where

```
private static class TestClass{
    private int i;
    private String s;

    public TestClass(Integer i, String s) {
        this.i = i;
        this.s = s;
    }
}
```

On my machine I got the following results:

```
Benchmark         Mode  Cnt   Score   Error  Units
MyBenchmark.str   avgt   20  47.695 ± 1.869  ns/op
MyBenchmark.tsts  avgt   20   6.999 ± 0.191  ns/op
```

Is it correct way to do this? Or I made some mistake in the benchmark and missed something?

Comment: Maybe the JVM optimized `new TestClass()` (bad name for a class, btw) to return the same single instance each time, thus invoking `i` and `str` (more bad names) only once each.

Comment: Speaking of bad names, overloading `str` to be two entirely different methods with the same name is another example.

Comment: @LewBloch Thats why I ask this. Maybe JVM did something that I didnt expect. Like returning the same instance all the time.

Comment: Now try with `-prof gc`, `-prof perfasm`, etc, and that would be enlightening. You have to analyse benchmarks before trusting them.

Answer (score 2):

This is because JIT knows the exact address of the literal String isntance ("asdasfa"). So in that case there is no need for creating a new object. You can clearly see it if you decompile str() method:

```
0x000000010dd1a2b0: sub    rsp,0x18
0x000000010dd1a2b7: mov    QWORD PTR [rsp+0x10],rbp  ;
0x000000010dd1a2bc: movabs rax,0x1bc1f1440    ;   {oop("asdasfa")}
0x000000010dd1a2c6: add    rsp,0x10
0x000000010dd1a2ca: pop    rbp
0x000000010dd1a2cb: test   DWORD PTR [rip+0xfffffffffe642d2f],eax           # 0x000000010c35d000;
0x000000010dd1a2d1: ret
```

The method consists of one instruction movabs rax,0x1bc1f1440 which puts an address to rax register, that's why it's a lot more faster. Other instructions are auxiliary.

For the other method str(Blackhole b) you will see a lot more including a compiled body of String constructor with getting a default charset and decoding of byte array through method call.